# Delete data from database older than two years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How can I delete the data from database(all tables) older than two years? I am using SQL server 2000. Please advise. I am not sure about foreign constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to delete records in a certain order if there are foreign key constraints.  You have to delete the "many" records that refer to "one" before you can delete "one".

It'll be a multi-step process:

1. Find all the primary keys in the "one" table using a timestamp (required) that's older than the cutoff date
2. Delete all the records from the "many" table whose foreign key column value are in the set of primary keys from step 1; repeat for all "many" tables that point to this "one" table
3. Delete all the records found in step 1 from the "one" table.
4. Repeat for all "one" tables with timestamps.

Comment: I think SSIS is the Microsoft ETL tool of choice now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

Comment: You could also define the foreign key constraint to cascade deletes, then just delete the topmost parent table.

Answer (score 0):

You need some timestamp, based on which you can delete records. Then you can use Scheduled Tasks to fire queries which delete old data.

Comment: cron ? Since when is SQL Server running on *nix ??

Comment: "cron" is *nix-speak for a 'scheduled task'.

Comment: CRON, Scheduled Tasks... same difference.